# Why did Pariston Hill leave the election stage out of a sudden?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

As I watched Hunter x Hunter on AnimaxTaiwan, I am not sure but probably Pariston won the election. Then he suddenly (probably) let Cheadle be the Chairman and left. If I am right, please explain his actions. If I am wrong, then please explain the election after the polls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pariston indeed *won* the election as Gon picked him because he knew Leorio afterall wanted to be a doctor. Also, take a look at the final result.

[image]

After that, Cheadle confronts Pariston in the hallway. These lines by Pariston might make you understand more about his action.

> - I didn't become vice chairman because I wanted to become chairman.
> - I just wanted to hinder the chairman.
> - When I said silly things to tease Netero, he always looked so happy...
> - I wanted to play with him some more.
>
> After he wipes his tears off...
>
> - Cheadle-san, if the Association becomes a dull place under your leadership...
> - I'll get serious about toying with you next time.

He likes to play around and enjoy himself, of course on the election too. According to Ging Freecss, Pariston's personality is similar to Netero's and his own. He's still care about the Association, like in the lines saying if Cheadle makes the Association become dull and boring, he will really make fun of her. But, instead of becoming the chairman, he prefer be the vice chairman and make fun of the chairman to satisfy himself.

Comment: Well where did he go?

Comment: He becomes the vice chairman.

Comment: newest chapter revealed that, he quitting election stage out because he want to join the expedition to the new world